# Question based on the paragraph above it

Tags: exam-questions

I had an English exam today, and none of the answers below seems right. However, if I had to choose one, I'd choose B.
But, I had to answer 15 questions and  this was the only one that could have a C answer, so I chose C.

I think it might be implied that one "can chow down on junk food" whether he likes it or not, so he has to eat junk food. And then, it is argued that this happens because vegan diets are "low in calcium, iron, vitamin D" and so on.
What do you think?

The paragraph is:

> Being vegan doesn't necessarily mean you're eating healthy. You can chow down on junk food - and miss out vital nutrients - whether you eat meat or not. For example, vegans diets are  naturally low in calcium, vitamin D, iron, vitamin B12, zinc and omega-3 fatty acids. If you are following a vegan diet it is important to include protein from foods such as nuts, seeds, beans and pulses. Of particular note are lentils, chickpeas, tofu and soya versions of milk and yogurt. Other good sources include cashew, pistachios, chia and pumpkin seeds, buckwheat and quinoa. At the same time, some vegans products contain a lot of coconut oil, for example, which is high in saturated fat. That said, it's easy to get the right food balance as a vegan, but you need to be aware of what you're eating - good advice for omnivores and herbivores alike."

The question is:

> "What does being a vegan mean?"
>   A. eating healthy and nutritious meals
>   B. paying attention to the food balance
>   C. having to eat junk food at times
>   D. casting aside prejudices about meat.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you think the answer is? Why? Why are you not sure? What makes this a difficult question for you?

Comment: I edited the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B, I suppose, but it's a poorly-worded question.

The paragraph doesn't say what being a vegan *is*.  It instead talks about some of the dietary concerns vegans *have*, and how they *should* manage those concerns.  It seems up to the individual to decide if they will follow this advice.

A better question would be

> According to the paragraph, what is something that vegans ought to do when it comes to their diet?

"Chow down" means to *indiscriminately eat* something.  The paragraph says that vegans *can* do this (and still be vegan) but it's better for them to make sure they get the proper nutrition from their food.  However, it does not say that vegans *must* occasionally eat junk food, so C is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It must be B,

A is directly contradicted by the first sentence.

C is not supported. It says that "You can chow down on [eat] junk" but this does not mean you have to eat junk.

There is no support for D in the text at all.

B is the best supported. It says "If you follow a vegan diet it is important to include protein from foods such as nuts [etc.]" So you should pay attention to food balance and eat the right balance of protein and fat (etc).